JDBC Driver not found in packaged JavaFX "jlink" app
I have installed MariaDB-JDBC-Java Driver V 3.3.3 from maven repo. When I issue mvn clean javafx:jlink the resulting Linux app does not start with an error, not finding the Driver:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

The command mvn clean javafx:run works just fine in Linux and Windows.
Please tell me why mvn target "javafx:jlink" is broken as soon as I write the dependency of the mariadb java connector into pom.xml?
I tried to substitue the mariadb java client with the mysql java connector in pom.xml and it has exactly the same behaviour.
I expected the packaged java app to connect via driver to the mariadb container as it is successfully doing on cmd line and IntelliJ IDEA - both Windows and Arch Linux.
-----------------module-info.java
module org.leder.gldisplaymanager {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires java.sql;


    opens org.leder.gldisplaymanager to javafx.fxml;
    exports org.leder.gldisplaymanager;
    exports org.leder.gldisplaymanager.gui;
    opens org.leder.gldisplaymanager.gui to javafx.fxml;

    uses java.sql.Driver;
}


UPDATE: I compiled a minimal example for IntelliJ project import and Linux app execution as follows -
expected result:
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host:address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=primary). Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt 
actual result:
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://localhost/display_manager 
intelliJ_project and Linux_app
UPDATE2:
pom.xml dependency is as follows:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>


Does your module-info.java contain uses java.sql.Driver;?

Not enough information. Is your app code modularized(JPMS)? What JDBC driver? What versions? Write a tiny app to demonstrate, with minimal code that you can post here entirely.

@VGR added uses directive - same errors

Please edit your question and include the dependency from your pom.xml that specifies the JDBC driver.

Here is a partially manual, imperfect solution that can still be executed.
Steps:
(1) open your intelliJ_project and Linux_app
(2) download mariadb.zip
(3) unzip mariadb.zip
(4) cd mariadb
(5) mvn package
generate output -> target/mariadb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
(6) mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=target/libs
generate -> target/libs include all jar files in this directory
(7) mvn javafx:jlink
generate -> target/app directory
(8) execute commands

cp target/libs/mariadb-java-client-3.3.3.jar  target/app/lib/
cp target/libs/caffeine-2.9.3.jar  target/app/lib/
cp target/libs/checker-qual-3.32.0.jar  target/app/lib/
cp target/libs/error_prone_annotations-2.10.0.jar  target/app/lib/
cp target/libs/jcl-over-slf4j-2.0.7.jar  target/app/lib/
cp target/libs/jna-5.13.0.jar  target/app/lib/
cp target/libs/jna-platform-5.13.0.jar  target/app/lib/
cp target/libs/slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar  target/app/lib/
cp target/libs/waffle-jna-3.3.0.jar  target/app/lib/
cp target/app/bin/app  target/app/bin/app.org

Copy MariaDB jar files to arget/app/lib/

mariadb-java-client-3.3.3.jar
caffeine-2.9.3.jar
checker-qual-3.32.0.jar
error_prone_annotations-2.10.0.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-2.0.7.jar
jna-5.13.0.jar
jna-platform-5.13.0.jar
slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar
waffle-jna-3.3.0.jar

(9) edit target/app/bin/app file
#!/usr/bin/env sh

##############################################################################
##
##  hellofx start up script for UN*X
##
##############################################################################

# Attempt to set APP_HOME
# Resolve links: $0 may be a link
PRG="$0"
# Need this for relative symlinks.
while [ -h "$PRG" ] ; do
    ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`
    link=`expr "$ls" : '.*-> \(.*\)$'`
    if expr "$link" : '/.*' > /dev/null; then
        PRG="$link"
    else
        PRG=`dirname "$PRG"`"/$link"
    fi
done
SAVED="`pwd`"
cd "`dirname \"$PRG\"`/.." >/dev/null
APP_HOME="`pwd -P`"
cd "$SAVED" >/dev/null

APP_NAME="hellofx"
APP_BASE_NAME=`basename "$0"`

# Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and HELLOFX_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=""

# Use the maximum available, or set MAX_FD != -1 to use that value.
MAX_FD="maximum"

warn () {
    echo "$*"
}

die () {
    echo
    echo "$*"
    echo
    exit 1
}

# OS specific support (must be 'true' or 'false').
cygwin=false
msys=false
darwin=false
nonstop=false
case "`uname`" in
  CYGWIN* )
    cygwin=true
    ;;
  Darwin* )
    darwin=true
    ;;
  MINGW* )
    msys=true
    ;;
  NONSTOP* )
    nonstop=true
    ;;
esac

CLASSPATH="$APP_HOME/lib/*"

JAVA_HOME="$APP_HOME"
JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"

# Increase the maximum file descriptors if we can.
if [ "$cygwin" = "false" -a "$darwin" = "false" -a "$nonstop" = "false" ] ; then
    MAX_FD_LIMIT=`ulimit -H -n`
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
        if [ "$MAX_FD" = "maximum" -o "$MAX_FD" = "max" ] ; then
            MAX_FD="$MAX_FD_LIMIT"
        fi
        ulimit -n $MAX_FD
        if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
            warn "Could not set maximum file descriptor limit: $MAX_FD"
        fi
    else
        warn "Could not query maximum file descriptor limit: $MAX_FD_LIMIT"
    fi
fi

# For Darwin, add options to specify how the application appears in the dock
if $darwin; then
    GRADLE_OPTS="$GRADLE_OPTS \"-Xdock:name=$APP_NAME\" \"-Xdock:icon=$APP_HOME/media/gradle.icns\""
fi

# For Cygwin, switch paths to Windows format before running java
if $cygwin ; then
    APP_HOME=`cygpath --path --mixed "$APP_HOME"`
    CLASSPATH=`cygpath --path --mixed "$CLASSPATH"`
    JAVA_HOME="$APP_HOME"
    JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"

    # We build the pattern for arguments to be converted via cygpath
    ROOTDIRSRAW=`find -L / -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d 2>/dev/null`
    SEP=""
    for dir in $ROOTDIRSRAW ; do
        ROOTDIRS="$ROOTDIRS$SEP$dir"
        SEP="|"
    done
    OURCYGPATTERN="(^($ROOTDIRS))"
    # Add a user-defined pattern to the cygpath arguments
    if [ "$GRADLE_CYGPATTERN" != "" ] ; then
        OURCYGPATTERN="$OURCYGPATTERN|($GRADLE_CYGPATTERN)"
    fi
    # Now convert the arguments - kludge to limit ourselves to /bin/sh
    i=0
    for arg in "$@" ; do
        CHECK=`echo "$arg"|egrep -c "$OURCYGPATTERN" -`
        CHECK2=`echo "$arg"|egrep -c "^-"`                                 ### Determine if an option

        if [ $CHECK -ne 0 ] && [ $CHECK2 -eq 0 ] ; then                    ### Added a condition
            eval `echo args$i`=`cygpath --path --ignore --mixed "$arg"`
        else
            eval `echo args$i`="\"$arg\""
        fi
        i=$((i+1))
    done
    case $i in
        (0) set -- ;;
        (1) set -- "$args0" ;;
        (2) set -- "$args0" "$args1" ;;
        (3) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" ;;
        (4) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" ;;
        (5) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" ;;
        (6) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" "$args5" ;;
        (7) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" "$args5" "$args6" ;;
        (8) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" "$args5" "$args6" "$args7" ;;
        (9) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" "$args5" "$args6" "$args7" "$args8" ;;
    esac
fi

# Escape application args
save () {
    for i do printf %s\\n "$i" | sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g;1s/^/'/;\$s/\$/' \\\\/" ; done
    echo " "
}
APP_ARGS=$(save "$@")



# Collect all arguments for the java command, following the shell quoting and substitution rules
eval set -- $DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS $CDS_JVM_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS $HELLOFX_OPTS -classpath "\"$CLASSPATH\"" org.leder.mariadb.HelloApplication "$APP_ARGS"

# by default we should be in the correct project dir, but when run from Finder on Mac, the cwd is wrong
if [ "$(uname)" = "Darwin" ] && [ "$HOME" = "$PWD" ]; then
  cd "$(dirname "$0")"
fi

exec "$JAVACMD" "$@"

(10) Test Run
./target/app/bin/app
you will get expected result: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host:address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=primary).
UPDATE - AUTOMATION in MAVEN
modify your pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.leder</groupId>
    <artifactId>mariadb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mariadb</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.10.0</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>                        
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>org.leder.mariadb/org.leder.mariadb.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          
 <plugin>
        <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <fileSets>
                <fileSet>
                  <sourceFile>${project.build.directory}/libs/caffeine-2.9.3.jar</sourceFile>
                  <destinationFile>${project.build.directory}/app/lib/caffeine-2.9.3.jar</destinationFile>
                </fileSet>
                

                <fileSet>
                  <sourceFile>${project.build.directory}/libs/checker-qual-3.32.0.jar</sourceFile>
                  <destinationFile>${project.build.directory}/app/lib/checker-qual-3.32.0.jar</destinationFile>
                </fileSet>


                <fileSet>
                  <sourceFile>${project.build.directory}/libs/error_prone_annotations-2.10.0.jar</sourceFile>
                  <destinationFile>${project.build.directory}/app/lib/error_prone_annotations-2.10.0.jar</destinationFile>
                </fileSet>
                
                <fileSet>
                  <sourceFile>${project.build.directory}/libs/jcl-over-slf4j-2.0.7.jar</sourceFile>
                  <destinationFile>${project.build.directory}/app/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-2.0.7.jar</destinationFile>
                </fileSet>
                
                
                <fileSet>
                  <sourceFile>${project.build.directory}/libs/jna-5.13.0.jar</sourceFile>
                  <destinationFile>${project.build.directory}/app/lib/jna-5.13.0.jar</destinationFile>
                </fileSet>

                <fileSet>
                  <sourceFile>${project.build.directory}/libs/jna-platform-5.13.0.jar</sourceFile>
                  <destinationFile>${project.build.directory}/app/lib/jna-platform-5.13.0.jar</destinationFile>
                </fileSet>


                <fileSet>
                  <sourceFile>${project.build.directory}/libs/slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar</sourceFile>
                  <destinationFile>${project.build.directory}/app/lib/slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar</destinationFile>
                </fileSet>
                
                <fileSet>
                  <sourceFile>${project.build.directory}/libs/waffle-jna-3.3.0.jar</sourceFile>
                  <destinationFile>${project.build.directory}/app/lib/waffle-jna-3.3.0.jar</destinationFile>
                </fileSet>
                
                
                <fileSet>
                  <sourceFile>${project.build.directory}/libs/mariadb-java-client-3.3.3.jar</sourceFile>
                  <destinationFile>${project.build.directory}/app/lib/mariadb-java-client-3.3.3.jar</destinationFile>
                </fileSet>
                <fileSet>
                  <sourceFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/dist/app</sourceFile>
                  <destinationFile>${project.build.directory}/app/bin/app</destinationFile>
                </fileSet>             
              </fileSets>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

add app file in your project folder (9)
reference step: (9) edit target/app/bin/app file <-- copy this file
(a) create dir dist under mariadb/src/main
(b) put app in (a)
(c) path mariadb/src/main/dist/app
Run in one command
mvn clean javafx:jlink com.coderplus.maven.plugins:copy-rename-maven-plugin:1.0:copy
Test
./target/app/bin/app
You can do it in one mvn command, you can skip Steps: (1) ~ (9)
Summary
(1) app contents is modify from Gradle pluginThe Badass Runtime Plugin。 I am reference from  https://github.com/beryx-gist/badass-runtime-example-javafx  (beryx-gist /
badass-runtime-example-javafx
Public)
(2) This answer is not good enough.　
If you already know how to perform the manual steps, you can rewrite the above content into an automated Maven configuration.
(3) final app dir
app
├── bin
│   ├── app     (New app file)
│   ├── app.org (original app file)
...
├── lib
│   ├── caffeine-2.9.3.jar
│   ├── checker-qual-3.32.0.jar
│   ├── error_prone_annotations-2.10.0.jar
│   ├── jcl-over-slf4j-2.0.7.jar
│   ├── jna-5.13.0.jar
│   ├── jna-platform-5.13.0.jar
│   ├── slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar
│   ├── waffle-jna-3.3.0.jar
│   ├── mariadb-java-client-3.3.3.jar
...


I need some time to test the steps given. But what is the root cause? Is it Maven? Am I fine if I switch to Gradle?

(1) I do't change any config or code of your project.  (2)  If you want to quick run ,  yes,  use Gradle , start with  https://github.com/beryx-gist/badass-runtime-example-javafx (beryx-gist / badass-runtime-example-javafx Public) (3)  Root cause , there is two type application: (a) non-modular application (b) modular application. Some tool or plugin can convert  non-modular jar to modular jar , but mariadb-java-client-3.3.3.jar is hard to describe in one word. So , quick and easy way is treat it like non-modular jar. Only one option, is badass-runtime.

(1) For modularized applications use the Badass-JLink plugin. (2) For non-modular application use the Badass Runtime Plugin. (3) Some non-modular jar (JDBC Driver jar) issue, you must use Badass Runtime Plugin.

I Update answer, now , you can do it in one mvn command.

hello @life888888 I successfully tested the command
./target/app/bin/app
Unfortunately zip file is generated in maven before the file mariadb-java-client-3.3.3.jar is copied to the lib directory! So the jar is missing in the archive: How can I change pom.xml to generate the complete zip file, too?

The following is an imperfect approach:
(1) Quick method, manually. Delete app.zip, and then compress target/app manually. (2) Pom.xml method, add exec, delete zip, and then compress target/app to generate app.zip
